# Markdown code indentation with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, markdown, middleman

I've been digging around for an answer for this since yesterday, and I'm stumped as to why is occurring...

We're delivering Markdown content through standard HAML templates (we're using the excellent static site generator Middleman to build, FYI), and Redcarpet to parse Markdown.

Everything is working as expected in terms of Markdown output, with the exception of code blocks:

**layout.haml** 
 (only a part of the file, showing a simple `=yield`. This `%section` is intended 6 spaces in the HAML file):

```
%section.content.main_content
  = yield
```

**index.html.md** 
 (only a part of the file, showing the code block code)

```
### Header Level 3
Here's some code:

    $total-columns  : 12;
    $column-width   : 4em;
    $gutter-width   : 1em;
    $grid-padding   : $gutter-width;
```

The output though, is not what we are expecting, and something is messing around with indentation. I'm unsure if HAML is the culprit, or what exactly is causing it:

Here is a screenshot of the browser output: http://bit.ly/JvjTYo

Here is a screenshot of the DOM from Chrome Developer Rools: http://bit.ly/JWprGO

We've tried a few different Any help is VERY welcome. If you want to see the full source on GitHub, let me know.

Comment: You posted two of the same links to your screenshots from the looks of it.

Comment: So sorry, this has been fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [Haml docs on whitespace](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_preservation). In this case you should be able to fix it by using the [`~` operator](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#tilde) instead of `=`:

```
%section.content.main_content
~ yield
```

Comment: Thank you @matt. This worked 100% as expected, without having to resort to :ugly output. I never knew about that operator, and I hope this helps someone else combining HAML with other whitespace-sensitive markup.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is HAML. It seems like it's trying to interpret and indent for you.

Do you have :ugly output on?

Also, do you have the below set for your pre tags?:

```css
pre { white-space:pre }
```

**EDIT:** Found this [Markdown Line Breaks in Code Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438050/markdown-line-breaks-in-code-blocks) which might help

Comment: :ugly output did the trick (which is too bad, since I love a nicely indented source). Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem! Danny, I'm not familiar with Middleman, but you could try setting environment specific variables if it runs a development server to set the :ugly setting.  I'm also not sure if Slim would treat the space better than HAML either. Just food for thought.

Comment: Silm **definitely** would, but I'm a HAML guy. :) Give Middleman a shot if you need to develop a static site, but still want a Ruby on Rails workflow. It's excellent.