# How to highlight Markdown code in Jekyll?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, jekyll, pygments, kramdown

I want to highlight markdown code in jekyll but I can't find a way how to do it. I looked at Pygement's lexers but I did not found one for markdown or kramdown.

I can highlight other codes but not markdown and kramdawn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax highlighting in jekyll using redcarpet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366095/syntax-highlighting-in-jekyll-using-redcarpet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rouge](http://github.com/jneen/rouge) or [Coderay](http://github.com/rubychan/coderay) for this purpose.

Comment: Your answer was the starting point, then it took a long way to actually make it work! :) I realized that kramdown applies coderay by default I only needed to build it locally and push the buid to github pages or my own host.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

````
```markdown
{% raw %}{% if page.tags %}...{% endif %}{% endraw %}
```
````