# Highlighting fenced code blocks in Jekyll using Pygments

Tags: jekyll, pygments

How to highlight fenced code block in Jekyll using Pygments?

````
```c
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   ...
}
```
````

doesn't work. I have to write like this:

```
{% highlight c %}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   ...
}
{% endhighlight %}
```

I don't like to use Liquid tags and I am using Kramdown.
I am not ready to switch from Kramdown to Redcarpet.
Rouge works fine with fenced code block but I want to use Pygments because it supports more programming languages.
[This problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648390/syntax-highlighting-markdown-code-blocks-in-jekyll-without-using-liquid-tags) is similar to mine except that it's too old.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll doesn't understand fenced code block out of the box. This can be easily resolved with the Github Flavored Markdown (aka GFM) parameter ([see documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#kramdown)).

In `_config.yml`, set :

```
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

**But** : Jekyll 3.x default highlighter is now [rouge](https://github.com/jneen/rouge), that does code highlight for [a lot of languages](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/list-of-supported-languages-and-lexers) and doesn't need python install.

Comment: But not for all the languages Pygments knows. And many people will have a Python install anyway.

Comment: Pygments support more languages than rouge. And even I set kramdown to accept GFM, the fenced code block is not rendered correctly.